# Problema al mostrar datos dentro de un rango de fechas

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, date

Tengo un input `date`:

```
<input id="start" type="date"><label>To</label><input id="end" type="date">
```

Resultado con formato `dd-mm-aaaa`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi `JS` al presionar `Generate Report`:

```
function Report(fecha1,fecha2)
{
        var fecha1 =document.getElementById("start").value;
        var fecha2 =document.getElementById("end").value;

        setTimeout(function(){ window.open("http://localhost/WareHouse/datereport.php?fecha1="+fecha1+"&fecha2="+fecha2, "_blank"); }, 1000);
        initArticles(); $('#myModalReport').modal('hide');
        console.log(fecha1);
        console.log(fecha2);
}
```

Al ejecutar los `console.log` se muestra en formato `aaaa-mm-dd`.

Al elegir un rango de fecha de genera un `PDF` trayendo los datos dentro de ese rango dependiendo su fecha de registro.

El problema es que la primera vez que pongo un rango en el `datepicker`, ejemplo `05-12-2018 a 12-12-2018` me trae los datos que efectivamente estan dentro de ese rango elegido el PDF se genera correctamente y en la parte inferior se muestra su `url` con formato `aaaa-mm-dd`, recargo la pagina y elijo nuevamente rango donde solo me deberia mostrar un dato y no muestra nada.

En mi `BD` tengo el tipo de dato `date`.
Imprimiendo el query desde php sale esto, tengo 2 registros dentro de los rangos mostrados dentro de la consulta, pero no los muestra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se debera por el tipo de formato que se esta manejando? No he encontrado solucion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el link que se muestra al final del PDF

Comment: Replanteo todo, ahi cree tablas con date y probe consultas y me devuelve todo ok, podrias hacer un echo desde el php de la query para ver como se arma en cada caso? Una de multiples fechas y una de un solo dia.

Comment: ¿Por que mandas la información mediante un header de la url? digo, es totalmente inseguro, y sobre lo que comentas, no tiene sentido, si la primera vez lo ejecutas, y generas un postback, y te deja de funcionar.

Comment: @Virus, el problema no está en tu código javascript (aunque no veo la razón de colocar el `window.open()` en un `setTimeout()`, y tal vez no esté en tu codigo php pero si no lo publicas ni tampoco el PDF que generas como te puedo ayudar?... Te recomiendo eches un paseito por [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)